# Django, url not found?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying out Python Django. With eclipse pyDev. But I'm unable to simply get my first url to display.

This urls.py is from the Cr package.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

This urlspy is from the Crowd package.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'Crowd/', include('Cr.urls'))
]
```

So what I've understood from this the `Crowd package` is the "main" webservice(?), and by using `include` I can whenever the regular expression matches `Crowd`, will pass it on to the  other `urls.py(Cr)`. But the debugger passes:

```
Using the URLconf defined in Crowd.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, crowd, didn't match any of these.
```

my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World!</h1>')
```

I tried to access it with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Crowd`

Below is an image of the project folder.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart your server? If it doesn't match, the error message, should at least list `Crowd/` as an option. Since it's not there, it seems your server is not using the code you're showing here.

Comment: I had used runserver --noreload. So I had to restart cuz of that. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: why no ^ in Crowd url?

Answer (score 1):

Can we see your settings.py file? There is a place in there where you define your project's url file. I'm assuming it's right now either not there or it's pointing to the wrong place, because Django can't find your urls.py file.

For example, in my settings.py file for one of my projects, I have:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Freya.urls'
```

Where "Freya" is my project name

Just for reference, not that I know this will solve your problem, this is what (part of) my urls.py file looks like for one of my projects:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
)
```

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'Crowd.urls' is written in mine.

Comment: Let me update my answer with something else @vandelay

Comment: Did not change anything. Do I have to reset the server or something similar for the effect?

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
          url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
          url(r'Crowd/', include('Cr.urls'))
```

]

just use this urls.py file

Comment: `include()` is unnecessary with `admin.site.urls`.

Comment: what include() do ?